# Why is there an apt-get script set in my cron.daily, I'm on Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, apt, cron, yum

I found this file tonight:

/etc/cron.daily/apt.cron

```
#!/bin/sh

[ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/apt ] && exit 0

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/apt ] && . /etc/sysconfig/apt

[ $CHECK_ONLY == "yes" ] && OPTS="$OPTS --check-only"
OPTS="$OPTS $EXTRA_OPTIONS"

export HOME=/root

if /usr/bin/apt-get -qq update; then
    /usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --check-only
    if [ $? -eq 100 ]; then
        /usr/bin/apt-get -q -y $OPTS dist-upgrade
    fi
fi
```

Questions:

1. **What's the deal, how did it get there?**
2. **What does it do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rpm -qf /etc/cron.daily/apt.cron
```

That's the rpm command which tells you which package a file comes from (if any). In this case, the file comes from the `apt` package, which you have installed on your system for some reason. This is the "apt-rpm" port, which, as the name implies, can handle Fedora's RPM packages. It's kind of interesting as a curiosity, but for most practical purposes, you really want `yum` or the newer `dnf`.

The script does what it says, basically: runs `apt-get dist-upgrade` daily, with quiet output and no prompts, and the options from `/etc/sysconfig/apt` if it exists.

Comment: If you don't have any particular reason for it, I'd suggest removing it. The native package managers are much better maintained.